# Use JavaScript and a button to calculate new value using user generated values

Tags: javascript

I'm still very new to javascript, so sorry is this is a basic question.  I've tried doing this several different ways, and have researched but can't quite find what I'm trying to do.

What I want to do is calculate the value of the product of two user created fields (hPlayed and hDealt) when the user clicks a button.  The values for hp and hd have been previously generated by the user using a button.  In my script they have variable names of hPlayed and bDealt, but in the below code I'm creating new variables called hPlayedInput and hDealtInput to represent them (which I realize may not be necessary, but I've tried using just those variables with a console.log as well).

Modified JS:

```
function handsPlayedRate() {
var hPlayedInput = document.getElementById("hp").value;
var hDealtInput = document.getElementById("hd").value;
var hRate = parseFloat(hPlayedInput) / parseFloat(hDealtInput);
document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML = hRate;
}
```

FULL (MODIFIED) HTML:

```
<button class="btnlost" onclick="handsPlayedMinus()">-</button>
<button class="btnwon" onclick="handsPlayedPlus()">+</button>
<p class="count" id="hp">0</p>

<button class="btnlost" onclick="handsDealtMinus()">-</button>
<button class="btnwon" onclick="handsDealtPlus()">+</button>
<p class="count" id="hd">0</p>

<button class="btnreset" type="button" onclick="handsPlayedRate()">Calculate&nbsp;Percent</button>
<p class="count" id="hr">0</p>
```

Comment: What elements are `hp` and `hd`? Can put your code into https://jsfiddle.net/ and link it here?

Comment: He can add it in a snippet right here. Click the snippet editor button

Comment: Add `document.` to your getElementById in all cases

Comment: Also change `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById` too and add `type="button"` to your button

Comment: I've made the typo changes you suggest and added the 'hp' and 'hd' elements to my code.  when I made those changes, i now get a result of NaN in the 'hr' element whereas before nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values you needed are not in an `input` field, you need to use `.innerHTML` to get the value.

```js
function handsPlayedRate() {
var hPlayedInput = document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML;
var hDealtInput = document.getElementById("hd").innerHTML;
var hRate = parseFloat(hPlayedInput) / parseFloat(hDealtInput);
document.getElementById("hr").innerHTML = hRate;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnlost" onclick="handsPlayedMinus()">-</button>
<button class="btnwon" onclick="handsPlayedPlus()">+</button>
<p class="count" id="hp">1</p>

<button class="btnlost" onclick="handsDealtMinus()">-</button>
<button class="btnwon" onclick="handsDealtPlus()">+</button>
<p class="count" id="hd">2</p>

<button class="btnreset" type="button" onclick="handsPlayedRate()">Calculate&nbsp;Percent</button>
<p class="count" id="hr">0</p>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I have what you have but I'm still getting NaN:

Comment: I altered my original code to show what I currently have now based on your suggestions, but I'm still getting NaN as a result.

Comment: Did you try `parseInt` or `parseFloat` ?

Comment: I used parseFloat (per your answer) and its in my above code mods.  What does parseFloat do differently?

Comment: My problem is still unsolved per my additional comments.

Comment: So, what is your actual question ?

Comment: The same question I had originally, but using the updated code in my original block.  I made the changes I believe you suggested, but it still does not work.  I get a result of NaN.

Comment: @PersephoneK, But in the above snippet I got the answer. right ? If you have any extra lines of code in between, please debug using console.log